# Substract strings - int result

Tags: c++

Can anyone explain why do I get the result `4` after using

```
a[]="informatics";
cout<<strchr(a, 't')-(a+3);
```

Shouldn't I get the result of `-4`?

Because I subtract a shorter string (`"tics"`) from `"ormatics"`. In my opinion, if I had `"ormatics-tics"` it would make sense to return a string, `orma`, not a number at all.

Why is that, I can't find reference of this thing. Also, when I tried the same thing, after I done myself what `strchr` returns, I got `-4`:

```
cout<<" tics"-"ormatics";`
```

Can someone explain please?

Comment: You're subtracting pointers, not strings.

Comment: You're subtracting pointers, not strings.

Comment: @owacoder but I'm doing 4-8 not 8-4

Comment: You're subtracting pointers, not strings.

Comment: @Isengardium You're subtracting pointers, not strings.

Comment: I looked away for like 3 minutes. What happened here?

Comment: Newbies don't have a place here, just understood.

Comment: @chris Looks like you were right :-P ...

Comment: @Isengardium It's not a problem that you're a newbie or not, it's just that you're asking the wrong type of question here. This is the kind of site that assumes you have read a significant bit of material(text from books) before coming here, not just a Google search or 1-2 random tutorials on the net.

Comment: @cst1992 actually I know way more than that, but I got it wrong with pointers and strings. Until now, I thought that when you point at a string, that pointer behaves just like a string. Btw, I'm not learning c++ from YouTube crappy tutorials, I'm at an informatics college. I'm a human, I make mistakes...

Comment: @Isengardium `I'm a human, I make mistakes` Exactly, that's why this site isn't fully automated. There are humans running it, and they're considerate, but a bit strict. You have to be, if you're running a site this big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a Pointer subtraction.

This is what is happening :

[image]

So `strchr(a, 't')-(a+3)` is,

```
(0+7)-(0+3) => 4
```

*Considering `a` to be `0` for simplicity *

> Note : When you subtract two pointers, as long as they point into the
>   same array, the result is the number of elements separating them

[Source](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html)

Answer (score 3):

`a` holds the pointer to the first character of the char array containing `"informatics"`.

`strchr(a, 't')` returns the pointer to the first "t" (which is the 8th character).
the result is `a+7`.

so your calculation resolves to:
`strchr(a, 't')-(a+3)` == `(a+7)-(a+3)` == `7-3` == `4`

**Edit:**
This answer is a bit misleading as it implies that `a` is a pointer.
This is wrong! `a` is an array and not a pointer.
The differences are best explained here: [c-faq - Arrays and Pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/)

A better wording would be that an array often is used like a pointer, as some operations simply use the address of the first element of the array.
A improved calculation could look like this:
`strchr(a, 't')-(a+3)` == `(&a[0] +7)-(&a[0] +3)` == `7-3` == `4`

*(Thank you Martin Bonner for pointing that out.)*

Comment: Oh, I see. I understand now. Thank you very much.

Comment: `a` does *not* hold the pointer to the first character of the char array.  It *is* the character array.  When it is used in an expression it will *usually* decay to a pointer to the first character.

Comment: @MartinBonner This is actually more accurate. Before i edit my answer in which use cases is this noticeable?  
`a[x]` for example is (AFAIK) equal to `*(a+x)`.

Comment: 1. sizeof.  2. Passing an array of size n to a function which takes a reference to an array of size n (very useful in templates - the template can deduce the size of the array).  3.  'extern char *a;' + 'char a[] = "abc";`.  There is a long rant about the difference between pointers and array in the C FAQ; it applied to C++ too.

Answer (score 1):

```
" tics"-"ormatics"
```

substracts two arbitrary `const char*` pointers. There can't be any prediction made about the difference.

There's absolutely no relation to their actual *string* contents.

Comment: In fact, it's worse than that.  If a program evaluates that expression, there can't be any prediction made about the results of that program.  (It is "undefined behaviour".)  For the avoidance of doubt: @πάνταῥεῖ knows this - but the OP probably doesn't.

Comment: @MartinBonner No _`" tics"-"ormatics"`_ isn't UB. It's just not giving a reasonably predictable result. That's vastly different from calling UB.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - It is - you can only subtract pointers if they're to elements of the same array (unless this rule is relaxed in C++ vs. C).

Comment: From http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf.  Last sentence of 5.7 [expr.add] para 5 "Unless both pointers point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the behavior is undefined."  The expression itself is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Well, there may be a thin line drawing here. The statement per se, won't ever call UB. Subsequent statements relying on it probably would.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Yes it will!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - In practice, perhaps.  According to the standard though, it's *this* statement that causes UB.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth:  Given that we are being language lawyers here: this is an expression, not a statement.

Answer (score 0):

Let me extend your example:

```
const char a[]="informatics";    // a is an array with 12 elements (inc terminator).
const char* const pa = a;        // pa is a pointer to char.  Let us say for the sake of 
                                 // argument it has value 0x1000
const auto pt = strchr(a,'t')    // pt will be a pointer with value 0x1007
const auto ap3 = a+3             // ap3 will be a pointer with value 0x1003
const auto diff = pt - ap3;      // diff will be type ptrdiff_t, and given the values
                                 // above, you shouldn't be surprised it has
                                 // value 4.
std::cout<<diff<<std::endl;      // Will output "4".
```

Comment: I understand now. Thank you.